# Как спроектировать структуру бд

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, проектирование

Помогите, как спроектировать БД и написать это все на entity Framework. Суть такова, есть список разных валют и пользователей, как мне сделать что бы у каждого пользователя был свой кошелек с этими валютами, во время работы приложения валют может стать больше, я думал сделать таблицу кошелька где первая колонка будет айди юзера и последующие колонки будут разными валютами, но как на ходу расширять список валют, тоесть добавлять столбец, ну и на уровне ентити нужно сделать что бы был доступ к счету юзера и количеству конкретной валюты у него по типу User.Withdraw.Curency если кто то знает как так сделать то скажите, или можете предложить совсем другую схему хранения

Comment: Таблица currency- для валют (id, iso, title), таблица user- для пользователей(id, name и тп.), таблица account -для кошельков (id, user_id, currency_id, amount). все id -FK, iso-уникальное. т.е. в итоге account связана с user и currency. для получения данных о сумме в опред валюте для опред пользователя, достаточно сделать выборку по account (если знаешь id пользователя)

Comment: как то так https://ibb.co/ZG52XvS

Comment: и еще уникальность в таблице account должна быть по полям user_id и currency_id (не указал сразу). все id -FK, опечатка все id - PK